# Zeros of linear combination of basis functions with infinite zeros

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose to consider a linear combination $f$ of real functions which are known to have infinitely many zeros on the real line (namely, I am considering the prolate spheroidal wave functions).

What can I say about the zeros of $f$? Are they also necessarily infinitely many? If not, is there a way to build a linear combination having no zeros on the real line (so a strictly positive linear combination)?

As a (perhaps) more intuitive example, what can I say about the zeros of a finite linear combination of ONLY cosine functions with different frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in (0,1), f_1(x)= \sin x +a$ and $f_2(x)= - \sin x+a$.

Then $(f_1+f_2)(x)=2a$ for all $x$.

Comment: I meant a linear combination of ONLY sine and cosine functions...otherwise, as you show, it's quite trivial...I am editing the question to specify this

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_1=cos(x)$ and $f_2=cos(\pi x)$. It is easy to see that all zeros of $f_1$ are irrational, and all of $f_2$ are rational.  Their intersection is thus empty.

Comment: That's right, but it does not answer the question. Can you find a linear combination of them which does not have any zeros?